# Geometry Nodes - How to procedurally subtract the unwanted part of a mesh after applying it with particles?

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]
This is how everything looks at the moment

[image]
This is what I expect the result to look like (partially instanced particles, partially original mesh)

[image]
The nodes setup

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways to do that: 1) With Geometry Nodes (GN) itself or 2) with Geometry Nodes (GN) and Shader Nodes (SH).

**Method 1:**

First distribute the ponits/particles then generate *volume mesh* from those points. Next, boolean the input mesh mesh with volume mesh and combine it with the points/particles mesh.

[image]

Blend File:
[image]

---

**Method 2:**
In this case, we generate a Vertex Color based on the distance to the points/particles then use this as mask in the Shader Nodes to make that area of mesh transparent,
[image]

Blend File:
[image]

Comment: Damn....wow. Learn every day here!! ;)

Comment: a little improvements suggestion: your links in your screenshots can hardly be seen... :(

Comment: @Chris Thanks I'll improve that. But links are visible in the full screen image. I have also added the Blend Files.

Comment: yes, with the blend files added - everything is great!!! ;) thanks for that great answer!!!